# Help with a 2level horizontal menu with MVC3 and razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to do a 2-level horizontal menu, like the one found here:
[TV.Com](http://www.tv.com/greys-anatomy/show/24440/news.html?tag=page_nav;subtabs;news)

I have searched on google but cant get it together.

Here's the sample i am using:

```
<div id="divNav">
<ul id="nav">

<li id="liRenaissance" class="off"><a href="#"><span>Renaissance</span></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Brunelleschi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alberti</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Palladio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Michelangelo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bramante</a></li>
</ul></li>  
<li id="liModern" class="on"><a href="#"><span>Modern</span></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sullivan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Le Corbusier</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gropius</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Yamasaki</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

The CSS is working, but how can i set this from the controller without using Request.Querystring.

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: I want to set the <li class="off"> to <li class="on"> through the controller, and how to know which menu is active

Answer (score 0):

This might make your life a bit easier: [ASP.NET MVC Sitemap provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup, I'm guessing you want to be able to set one of the menus to "on" and the other to "off" based upon your location on the site.

If you are reluctant to use the Request.Querystring within the masterpage itself, you could:

1. Use a codebehind on your master page This is a bit outdated, as codebehinds are avoided within MVC, however it would work in separating your concerns for a masterpage which typically has no controller.
2. Use a RenderAction to reference a
   controller which will handle menu
   generation.

Number 2 is probably your best bet.

Comment: I dont use Masterpage, i use _layout, so no codebehind. Can you please give me an sample how you mean with the number 2 choice ?

Comment: In that case I believe you should be able to use the ViewBag to give it the value from the controller, which is even easier.

Comment: i tried that, or i used the xviewmodel and added a property to it. The li looked like this <li class="@Model.Nav"> but some how I didn't got it to work. Because then it set all the <li> classes to on, so all the links where shown.